# Как через .htaccess обрезать GET-параметры?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть страница http://site.ru/sovety/magazin/

Также есть страницы

http://site.ru/sovety/magazin/?_escaped_fragment_=digiseller/detail/1254215
http://site.ru/sovety/magazin/?_escaped_fragment_=digiseller/detail/4655618
http://site.ru/sovety/magazin/?_escaped_fragment_=digiseller/detail/7446526

и другие, отличающиеся последним набором цифр.

Как со всех этих страниц сделать перенаправление на http://site.ru/sovety/magazin/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас версия apache 2.4 или выше, то попробуйте так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/magazin/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://site.ru/sovety/magazin/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

а если меньше, то:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/magazin/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://site.ru/sovety/magazin/? [R=301,L]
```